# Display images with thumbnail and next/prev buttons

Tags: javascript

I am creating a newspaper site and displaying each page in thumbnail. Upon clicking of thumbnail it shows the corresponding image in main area. Now I want to put next/prev buttons also. how can i do this.

```
// change image on click of thumbnails
$(".thumb").click(function() {
    //$("#mainimage").attr("src", $(this).attr("alt"));
    var href = $(this).attr("alt");
    $('#mainimage').parent().attr('href', href);
    $("#mainimage").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).load(function() { $(this).fadeIn(); });
        $(this).attr("src", href);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application needs to know which thumb is currently active before you can add next and previous functions. Assuming I've interpretted your question correctly, the following should do the trick:

```
// change image on click of thumbnails
$(".thumb").click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("alt");
    $('#mainimage').parent().attr('href', href);
    $("#mainimage").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).load(function() { $(this).fadeIn(); });
        $(this).attr("src", href);
    });
    //record which thumb was clicked
    $(".thumb").removeClass("active");//remove class
    $(this).addClass("active");//apply class to selected thumb
});

//move next
$(".next").click(function(){
    if($(".thumb.active").next(".thumb").length>0){
        $(".thumb.active").next().trigger("click");
    } else {
        $(".thumb:first").trigger("click");//go to first
    }
    return false;
});

//move previous 
$(".prev").click(function(){
    if($(".thumb.active").prev(".thumb").length>0){
        $(".thumb.active").prev().trigger("click");
    } else {
        $(".thumb:last").trigger("click");//go to end
    }
    return false;
});

//click the first thumb to begin
$(".thumb:first").trigger("click");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Bgj4b/

Comment: Thanks Moob, it really helps in this situation and to learn some new things. Thanks.